# How to implement async actions in react-actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-actions

I can't seem to find any example which shows how to implement an async action using redux-actions library. Have searched their github repo: https://github.com/reduxactions/redux-actions but can't seem to find any example.

Does redux-action even allow you to implement an async action?

Looking for any example of doing async action with redux-thunk.

Comment: Use redux-thunk (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Redux: Action dispatched, return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981460/react-native-redux-action-dispatched-return-results)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs it looks like that library is only meant to create and compose action creators. For asynchronous actions you'll still need to add something to facilitate that. There are a number of different middleware you can work with. [Thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and [sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) are two of the more popular ones but there are many.